# Tabularx and short caption causes error

Tags: captions, tabularx

I'm trying to construct a multi-page, landscape table with variable column widths. It was working until I started to get a problem with the caption. If I try to include a short caption I get the error "Missing number, treated as zero \end{tabularx}" and "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \end{tabularx}".

Below is a minimal non-working example. I'm sure it was working earlier and I'm not sure what I've done to break it.

```
% New template
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}

%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx} % For paragraph cells in tables
\usepackage{ltablex} % allows tabularx over multiple pages. May need to be compiled a couple of times. 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\footnotesize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\footnotesize\hsize=.3\hsize}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% May need following command to avoid problems with other tables
%\keepXColumns
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ssssbbbbb}
\toprule
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8 & col9 \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\caption[short caption]{long caption {\label{lit_review}}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ltablex` redefines `\caption` incorrectly, you should have used  `ltxtable` :-)

The simplest fix is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}

%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx} % For paragraph cells in tables
\usepackage{ltablex} % allows tabularx over multiple pages. May need to be compiled a couple of times. 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\footnotesize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\footnotesize\hsize=.3\hsize}X}


\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% May need following command to avoid problems with other tables
%\keepXColumns
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ssssbbbbb}
\toprule
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8 & col9 \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\ifx\caption\savecaption
\caption[short caption]{long caption {\label{lit_review}}}
\fi
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\caption` has to be outside of the `tabularx` environment but inside a float environment, such as `\begin{table}...\end{table}`.

**Edit**:

Although my answer compiles, my explanation was incorrect.  See David Carlisle's answer and comment for an explanation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}

%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx} % For paragraph cells in tables
\usepackage{ltablex} % allows tabularx over multiple pages. May need to be compiled a couple of times. 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\footnotesize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\footnotesize\hsize=.3\hsize}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% May need following command to avoid problems with other tables
%\keepXColumns
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ssssbbbbb}
\toprule
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8 & col9 \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption[short caption]{long caption {\label{lit_review}}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, ltablex defines tabularx to be longtable which defines \caption, ltablex redefines caption incorrectly. As the OP says, it works if you do not use the optional argument

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I up voted your answer.